# how to have an icon when calling a object value meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, mean-stack, meteor-packages

here is my code:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="mdi mdi-comment">
  {{pluralize commentsCount "comment"}}
</a>
```

the icon I would to use is specified in the class, and I used the meteor-material-icons package. I would like to remove the "comment" from inside the value call, and just have the icon and the value be displayed.

Any help with be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right. Seems like you need to replace `{{pluralize commentsCount "comment"}}` with just `{{commentsCount}}`

Comment: That actually solved my problem. Thank you